# android can not find a target

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

i am using eclipse with android plugin and sdk, but i can not create a virtual device due to there is no target,  and when I execute this:

```
  $ ./android list targets
   Available Android targets:
```

what should i do?

and..............

when i try to install the available packages in eclipse avd manage it comes to:

Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.0 API5, revision1
SSL peer shutdown incorrectly....

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Run tools/android to retrieve targets. It'll load up a gui interface, under settings check the box that says force https to be fetched using http. Then go to Available packages and select the version of Android you want. The targets are not downloaded by default in the latest sdk release.

At least that's what you get on windows, I don't have a linux machine available at the moment but the tools/android tool was created to manage targets and avds.

Comment: All tutorials try to explain every bit of building an app, but they run over things like this, it's frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and had to go to Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Android to set the Android SDK location (C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk in my case).

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the android application and tell it to fetch the sources from the Android repositories. See this post for an explanation: http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=96

Answer (score 2):

I restarted eclipse with "eclipse -clean" and this solved my problem.... I do not know if restarting also will solve the problem