# Add SDK to eclipse and no Target

Tags: java, android, api, sdk, target

I have installed android SDK in my computer successful.but when i configure the environment in eclipse.it show "No target available". Actually,i had loaded API form 1.6 to 4.0.I tried many ways to slove the question.but all is failure.now,i have no idea already.who can help me. i would thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the ADT Plugin for Eclipse? If you are you can easily configure Eclipse for Android Development. Android site says -

> Select Window > Preferences... to open the Preferences panel (Mac OS
>   X: Eclipse > Preferences). Select Android from the left panel. You may
>   see a dialog asking whether you want to send usage statistics to
>   Google. If so, make your choice and click Proceed. You cannot continue
>   with this procedure until you click Proceed.
>
> For the SDK Location in the main panel, click Browse... and locate
>   your downloaded SDK directory. Click Apply, then OK.

For more information you visit their configuration page - http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#configuring. Hope this helps

[image]

Ok so now did you first try out the option in the Options menu -
[image]

But if this doesn't work it means there is something wrong that is happening due to conflicts in OS. I would like to know what is your Desktop Environment? Ubuntu? Window? Mac?

I'll assume that your using a Windows environment... The best option the community has noted down is the usage of Force HTTPS resources to be downloaded via HTTP. You could also use a Proxy and get the URLs fetched.

For more information look at this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/63a44163a8d07cd9?pli=1).

Comment: Thanks,I also doubt my ADT is failed to install.And i have already install it again.But i get into another trouble.I delete the early SDK and install again.however the SDK is failed to install all the time.It show "Failed to fetch URL https".After i change the choose in "setting",it show "Failed to fetch URL http".I don't know how to do.Do you know? And could you tell me?

Comment: First of all remove all trails of Android from your PC... This includes SDK and other directories located under the SDK folder. After that take a Fresh Install and look at the edited question now...

Comment: Yeah,you are right.my Desktop Environment is Windows 7(64 bit).I had already attempted your method.However there are only Android SDK Tools revision 15  could be installed.I forgot to tell you the Android SDK i used is r05,and i install SDK r16 successful once.Because in the SDK r16 the adb.exe is in the platform-tools folder and it is not in tools folder.It will cause error when configure eclipse to point to the SDK.It is so difficulty.I will lose my hope soon.

Comment: Congrats happy developing Android

Answer (score 4):

You need to do all of the following:

1. Download and install Java and Eclipse
2. Download and install the Android SDK
3. Install the Android plug-in for Eclipse (from Help, Install Software)
4. Configure Eclipse to point to your SDK
5. Create an Android virtual machine (for emulation)
6. Create an Android project (for your app)

Q: It sounds like maybe things are going wrong at Step 4, correct?

Q: If so, can you browse to the directory with your SDK (for example, from Eclipse can you browse to "C:\program files (x86)\android\android-sdk")?

Comment: Also - look at this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671462/android-can-not-find-a-target

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have made some other attempts.and i doubt my Android plug-in for Eclipse installing is failed. So i tried again follow with your steps.but it's so sad,my SDK is failed to install all the time.I have already tried various SDK.In addition to SDK r16 & r15 is succcessful all is failed.and I want early SDK,such as r05.It show "Failed to fetch URL https".and I change it in "setting".but it show "Failed to fetch URL http".I don't know how to do. My god,I had already worked two whole days for this.Could you help me?Tell me it's why and how to do.

Comment: Just a quick addition to this: after step 2, you need to run the SDK Manager and download the platform SDKs you want to use.  If you don't do this before step 4, *you have to restart Eclipse to get it to see the platforms*, as it will only read the list of available targets once per session.  I believe you can also trick it into rereading the list by copying your SDK to a different location and then pointing it at the new copy, but it's probably easier just to restart it.