# No build tools installed in the SDK (sdk tools already installed)

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having trouble exporting my first APK in eclipse. When I click on finish, I get the message: `No build tools installed in the SDK.`

I've googled the problem but all the results say that i have to install `Android SDK Tools`, but I have it and it's been updated (22.0.1).
Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have ALL the packages installed but still the same error.

Ubuntu 12.04
Eclipse 3.8.0
JDK 7

Answer (score 5):

From version 22 forward the build tools is a separate package. Open then Android SDK Manager and check Android SDK Build-tools and click install. The package will download and you'll be able to export/build.

[image]

Comment: yes, i have it also installed!, now im installing all of the other Android versions, but i dont think thats the problem

Comment: I have already that installed but Still the Issue, Using Ubuntu x64, Eclipse Platform Version: 3.8.0, JDK 7

Comment: Please verify that you have the 64-bit version of the SDK installed

Comment: I have the 32-bit installed, im downloading the 64-bit version, ill let you know

Answer (score 2):

If eclipse is pointing to the wrong Android SDK it won't find the build tools. If you're sure you installed the right build tools, it may be that eclipse is pointed to the wrong directory. So if you're on windows, in eclipse, goto Window -> Preferences -> Android, and check the field in "SDK Location" eclipse is looking for the build tools in a subdirectory of that folder. Goto that folder and run the SDK Tools.exe and install everything in that GUI and it should work. Otherwise, change the path to your other SDK installation.
Here's a kinda same tutorial for Mac:
[Add SDK to eclipse and no Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440493/add-sdk-to-eclipse-and-no-target)

Comment: I found that I had an old installation in a different folder and the path was leading to it. (interesting sidenote: Installing the base package on windows gives errors sometimes about the path name being too long. My fix for this was to shorten the name of the folder from which I installed it - and moved it up a couple of levels.)